# Как отследить удаление символов из input?

Tags: vue.js, typescript

Есть 4 инпута для ввода кода. Каждому присвоил :data-id="index". code содержит 4 пустые переменные value
Для перехода к следующему после заполнения одного инпута использую:

```
const nextStep = (value: string) => {
  if (value && !isNaN(+value)) {
    const element = document.activeElement as HTMLElement
    if (element.dataset.id) {
      const id = +element.dataset.id
      if (id < code.length - 1) {
        const nextVal = document.querySelector(`input[data-id='${id + 1}']`) as HTMLElement
        nextVal.focus()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Как отследить удаление символов, чтобы перейти к предыдущему?